# Getting the checked states of a radio button in all the items in a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` which holds 10 views each having a `CheckBox`. Now, in my main activity when a menu button named "POST" is pressed I want to know whether all the `CheckBox` in each of the views of the `RecyclerView` is checked or not.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to pass additional variable `isChecked` inside every model of a list of models passed to RecyclerView.
Like that:

```
public class Model {
    private boolean isChecked;

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }
}
```

Then inside your RecyclerView ViewHolder, create a constructor:

```
public ListViewHolder(View view) {
   super(view);
   switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.add_switch);
   switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                getItemAt(getLayoutPosition()).setChecked(isChecked);
            }
   });
}
```

Then to get all button states just iterate through the list of models in Your activity:

```
public boolean areAllChecked() {
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
         Model model = adapter.getItemAt(i);
         if (!model .isChecked()) {
             return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a boolean `isChecked` in your model class (Item which you are adding to `RecyclerView` Adapter)
2. In your adapter `onBindViewHolder` implement `onCheckedChangeListener` for your checkbox and set `isChecked` appropriately.
3. implement a `isChecked(int position)` method in your adapter. It should return checked value of the items specified by `position`
4. in your fragment/activity iterate through adapter items and find out if all items are checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Track the state of each checkbox in the adapter.
To do so let it have an map that stores a boolean value bound to a unique key for each checkbox. And also let it implement the *OnCheckedChangeListener*.

```
MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
   private Map<Object, Boolean> checkboxStates = new HasMap<>();

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
      checkboxStates.put(buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
   }

   public Map<Object, Boolean> getCheckboxStates() {
     //We don't want the caller to modify adapter state.
     return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.checkboxStates);
   }

   //other code
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     //your code
     CheckBox cb; 
     //assuming that we have the reference to the cb view
     //also assuming that cb has a unique identifiable tag assigned from the model
     cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

     if (this.checkboxStates.containsKey(cb.getTag()) {
       cb.setChecked(this.checkboxStates.get(cb.getTag());
     } else {
       this.checkboxStates.put(cb.getTag(), cb.isChecked());
     }
   }
}
```

With this you can call the *getCheckboxStates* to get the states of each checkbox that was visible.

The key point here is that you need something unique identifiable for each item in the dataset that can be used as a tag for each checkbox that represents that item.